# How do I make this flex grandchild show the scrollbar?

Tags: css

I have a CSS issue here and I cannot figure out how to solve it.
I would like the `.panel-extra-content` section to have a scrollbar but it seems it is not working for some reason. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

```css
.panel {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
}

.panel-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.panel-extra-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="info" tabindex="0"><span>Number</span></div>
    <div class="panel-extra-content">
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <button>hey</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order for it to be scrollable, you need to add a height to the .panel-extra-content class, eg:

```css
.panel {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
}

.panel-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.panel-extra-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}

.child {
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="info" tabindex="0"><span>Number</span></div>
    <div class="panel-extra-content">
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
      <div class="child">Child</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <button>hey</button>
  </div>
</div>
```